# hashcat for md5($salt.$pass)

Tags: md5, hashcat

How could i use hashcat to crack this hash?

Syntax:

`md5(eWVzX3RoaXNfaXNfdmVyeV9sb25nX3NhbHRfdG9vpassword@123) = 531e89f00f009ced5e0001e33758d3c3`

Salt: eWVzX3RoaXNfaXNfdmVyeV9sb25nX3NhbHRfdG9v

Plaintext: password@123

MD5: 531e89f00f009ced5e0001e33758d3c3

I have used following syntax and got **Line-length exception** error.

Syntax used:

1. `hashcat -a 0 -m 0 hash_pass rockyou.txt`
2. `hashcat -a 0 -m 30 hash_pass rockyou.txt`

Error:

`Hashfile 'hash_pass' on line 1 (eWVzX3RoaXNfaXNfdmVyeV9sb25nX3NhbHRfdG9vpassword@123): Line-length exception`

I know the salt.
I have a wordlist.
I have MD5 of above, i.e. md5($salt.$pass)

I am not sure, how to use hashcat to solve this challenge.

Request help.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the salt is '123'.

```
$ echo -n 'password123' | md5sum
482c811da5d5b4bc6d497ffa98491e38  -

$ cat test.hash
482c811da5d5b4bc6d497ffa98491e38:123

$ echo "password" | hashcat --quiet -m 10 -a 0 -o test.out test.hash
$

$ cat test.out
482c811da5d5b4bc6d497ffa98491e38:123:password
```

(Note that --quiet is optional, and there to make my demonstration output simpler. And I use -a 3 for simplicity also, your attack will vary)

Comment: How would i actually do this the other way around? i cant seem to figure this out..
i hava a hash (which i assume is md5($s.$p) ), and i know the password, but how would i derive the SALT from this using hashcat ?    thx in advance!

Comment: With hashcat, you just use the hash type that swaps the $s and $p, as if the password is the "salt" and you're cracking the "password" (the salt). So if you are using -m 10, switch to -m 20 (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the right hash mode in HashCat. As you have salt before password it is md5($salt.$pass) -> mode 20.

[image]

2. Provide both hash and salt to Hashcat (in your hash_pass file).
   File format: `$hash:$salt`,
   In your case hash_pass should contain: `531e89f00f009ced5e0001e33758d3c3:eWVzX3RoaXNfaXNfdmVyeV9sb25nX3NhbHRfdG9v`
3. Put everything together and enjoy:

```
hashcat -a 0 -m 20 hash_pass rockyou.txt
```